# Selenium Marionette WebDriverException: File not found

Tags: java, selenium, automation, firefox-marionette

while trying to upload an file via selenium I get the following error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: File not found: D:\Projekte\Ticket.xml (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'r-177', ip: '172.16.18.177', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Session ID: ec651a7b-bca2-48f0-8dd3-9e3bfde44c1c
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=47.0, browserName=Firefox, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, rotatable=false, appBuildId=20160604131506, takesElementScreenshot=true, command_id=1, version=, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAE+LyUgAAAAAAAAAA..., platformVersion=6.1, platformName=Windows_NT, proxy={}, device=desktop, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
```

INFO: Two days ago I had FireFox 46, instead of MarionetteDriver I used FirefoxDriver. All worked well. Now after the auto-update to FireFox 47, I have some problems.

This is how Driver is setup

```
FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", this.workingDir);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

// System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/Entwicklung/marionette/wires.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/Entwicklung/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe");

DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fxProfile);
// dc.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
// dc.setCapability("marionette", true);

this.driver = new MarionetteDriver(dc);
```

Here's the JAVA

```
WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id$=\"uploadComp_input\"]"));

field.sendKeys("D:\\Projekte\\Ticket.xml" + Keys.TAB);
```

Documentation on WWW seems to be rare since FireFox 47 is quiet new, hopefully I find someone who can support me.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Your code seems fine to me so unless D:\Projekte\Ticket.xml is an invalid path it might be a bug in the MarionetteDriver + FF47 combo

Comment: Hey RemcoW, yes the path exists. I will file an Issue on GitHub for MarionetteDriver, hopefully someone will respond there.

Comment: See here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1279854

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday, after my firefox auto-updated to FF 47. I don't think the current version of Selenium is compatible with FF 47.

This is how I fixed it:
 1. Uninstall FF 47.
 2. Install FF 46, if you are using Selenium 2.53
 3. Turn off FF auto-update in your FF options
 4. Run your selenium code

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Smokey, that is not an solution for my problem, just an workaround. What indeed would help for now, but this project will be in development still some time so I have to look for an "real" solution for my usecase...